# Illegal ioctl for device error when using fgets() to read characters from a file

Tags: c, io

I'm trying to write a simple C program to read a certain amount of characters from a file at a time and then store this in a variable. For instance, 10 characters at a time.

I'm trying to do this using fgets() , but it keeps returning the error 
FAILED: illegal ioctl for device which I cannot troubleshoot and can't find after searching for some information about it.

I've tried to rewrite my code several times, and read through the documentation but I still cannot find the root of the problem.

Here is my code:

Main function (I've already done argument checks but omitted them for simplicity)

```c
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file;
    file=check_file(argv[1]);
    readCharacters(file);
    return 0;
}
```

check_file function

```
FILE * check_file(char *fileName)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    if(!file) {
        perror("SENDER: File does not exists");
        fclose(file);
        exit(1);
    }
    return file;
}
```

Read Characters function

```
void readCharacters(FILE* fp) {
    char buff[TOTALCHAR], *result;


if ((result = fgets(buffer,TOTALCHAR,fp)) != NULL)
      printf("The string is %s\n", result);
    else if (ferror(fp)) {
      perror("FAILED");
    } else {
      printf("EOF was reached");
    }
```

If my text file is:

"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

**Expected result:**

First String = "The quick brown"
Second String = " fox jumps over" 
etc

**Actual result:**

EOF was Reached

EDIT: I've updated my code after an answer to the original question and it turns out that EOF is reached. However, the file I'm reading in is definitely not empty

Answer (score 0):

This call

```
result = fgets(buff,TOTALCHAR,fp))
```

will return `NULL` on error, but *also* if EOF is reached. This is *not* necessarily an error condition. You have to distinguish manually, for example  by using the `ferror()` function:

```
if ((result = fgets(buff,TOTALCHAR,fp)) != NULL)
   printf("The string is %s\n", result);
else if (ferror(fp)) {
    perror("FAILED");
} else {
    printf("EOF was reached");
}
```

You assumed that EOF is an error and `perror()` will just output the last thing, that `errno` was set to. In this case, it was probably some internal libc-call to `ioctl()`.

If this branch

```
printf("The string is %s\n", result);
```

is never taken, then the file you open has to be empty (i.e. it sreturn EOF on the first read attempt)

Comment: Thank you, it turns out that EOF was reached. I do not know why this is the case though, because my file is over 200 characters long and it definitely isn't empty. Do I need to open the file again in readCharacter() or has that already been handled in check_file ?

Comment: @CizzleP No, you do not need to reopen the file; Is it a simple text file? The error seems to be sublte, to save some time: Post the _full_ code in your question, Post the exact textfile you have and show, how you start your program. If there are any other notable circumstances, tell us.

Comment: It is just a simple text file, just like my example. It's passed in through the command line

Comment: @CizzleP As I said, the behavior is not explainable with the information you provide. Provide more details, as I already requested, otherwise noone can help you

Comment: I compile my code in the standard way using cc filename.c -o output file which works fine. I then run my code like so ./output input.txt where input is the text file. It is in the same directory

Comment: I've ran cat input.txt before and it does output the files contents so it's not empty

Comment: @CizzleP I just tested it, just to be sure, and it worked as expected. Check your setup closely, there must be a subtle problem somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @Ctx think I'm going to run it in a different setup and see what happens. It's driving me mad haha